# Using custom diff tool with `git show`

Tags: git

With git I can set a custom diff tool that is used for certain file extensions by the following in `.git/config`

```
[diff "csv_diff"]
    command = Tools/csv_diff
```

and this in `.gitattributes` (in the root of the repository)

```
*.csv diff=csv_diff
```

This works when using `git diff`, but it doesn't work with `git show`. My question is, how do I use a custom tool with `git show`?

Comment: "restrict git show to only use that custom diff tool on certain file extensions" - What exactly does that behavior look like? What should happen when you `show` a diff that affects multiple files, some with extensions in that category and some not?

Comment: The same thing `git diff` does. The files with the specific extension use the custom tool, files with other extensions use the default tool.

Comment: Seems like you're going to have to do something like write a script that wraps `git diff x^..x` and alias `show` to it.

Comment: Oh, I suppose you also need to consider what it should do for merge commits.

Comment: I believe Git cannot invoke other tools for `git show` since that’s the command that is used for generating patches :/

Comment: Did you try `--ext-diff` ?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski You might want to post that as an answer :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski that worked. You should make that an answer.

Comment: @poke done :) since it was in the docs, I figured OP has already tested that one and something didn't work.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski It’s not the first time some Git feature is hidden somewhere within the docs ;) Well spotted!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for the `--ext-diff` option.

Here's what [`git show` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) say about it:

> **--ext-diff**
>
> Allow an external diff helper to be executed. If you set an external diff driver with [`gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), you need to use this option with [`git-log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and friends.

Comment: How to use `--ext-diff`? Just like `git show --ext-diff=meld git_hash_id`?Could you please show me a simple example?

Comment: I found neither `git show --ext-diff=meld git_hash_id` nor `git config --global diff.tool meld; git show --ext-diff git_hash_id` works. I can't figure out where goes on.Could you please shed some light on this matter?

Comment: Someone found a way to make this the default?

Answer (score 14):

Like @LucasTrzesniewski said, you can use `--ext-diff` from the command line to set a diff for the current session.

You can also use the [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) to set the git-diff perfile.

A git diff implementation exists of 2 parts:

- A definition in `$GIT_DIR/config` or `$HOME/.gitconfig`
- A bound between a file and a definition in `gitattributes`

Git has choosing for this design to separate the executable code from the source code, this makes it impossible for a `git clone` or other git command to run any harmful code.

### Writing a definition

To write a definition, we start with a header consisting of `[diff "namehere"]`, then followed by a line-break.

The next line consists of the command definition, this line is as follows: `command = commandlinehere`. This command is then called with 7 arguments if it is ran, these are documented for the [GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) enviroment vriable in the docs.

> **`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`**
>   When the environment variable GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF is
>   set, the program named by it is called, instead of the diff invocation
>   described above. For a path that is added, removed, or modified,
>   `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` is called with 7 parameters:
>
> ```
> path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode where:
> ```
>
> **<old|new>-file** are files GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF can use to read the
>   contents of <old|new>,
>
> **<old|new>-hex** are the 40-hexdigit SHA-1 hashes,
>
> **<old|new>-mode** are the octal representation of the file modes.
>
> The file parameters can point at the user’s working file (e.g.
>   new-file in "git-diff-files"), /dev/null (e.g. old-file when a new
>   file is added), or a temporary file (e.g. old-file in the index).
>   `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` should not worry about unlinking the temporary file, it is removed when `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` exits.
>
> For a path that is unmerged, `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` is called with 1
>   parameter, <path>.
>
> For each path `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` is called, two environment variables,
>   `GIT_DIFF_PATH_COUNTER` and `GIT_DIFF_PATH_TOTAL` are set.

The total example looks like this:

```
[diff "jcdiff"]
command = j-c-diff
```

### Writing the gitattributes

We need to modify our gitattributes to use our custom driver. The gitattributes file consist of a syntax similar to `filename value [value2 [value3 [value4 [...]]]]`.

**Examples:**

```
*           diff=jcdiff
```

<sup>We to use our custom git diff for every file.</sup>

```
*.java      diff=javadiff
*.python    diff=pythondiff
```

<sup>Use javadiff for java files, pythondiff for python files.</sup>

```
*           diff=globaldiff
*.java      diff=javadiff
```

<sup>Use javadiff for java files, globaldiff for remaining files.</sup>

### Configuring git to automatically set `--ext-diff`

You can add an alias using `git config alias.showobject 'show --ext-diff'` to define a new command called `git showobject` that automatically uses our filter.

Comment: This is what I had originally (before I asked the question). It works perfectly when using `git diff`, but with `git show`, the `--ext-diff` argument must be given for `git` to use the tool specified in the `config` and `.gitattributes` file.

Comment: There does not seem to be a way to force `--ext-diff` within git, right? The only possible workarounds I found are to use a git alias (as in the answer above, i.e., setting up another command name) or using a shell alias.

Answer (score 8):

As an alternate answer for others in search of using a diff tool like [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) with `git show`

```
git difftool --tool=meld HEAD~..HEAD
```

Most of the time I like to see my small diffs on the command line because it's quick, but every once in a while I do want to boot up a diff tool  to inspect things a little deeper - especially with the work of others. But this excludes the ability to use `.gitattributes` because this would then be the default behavior.

In order to show a particular commit or branch, then I've created this alias in my `~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    showm = "!f(){ if [ -z $1 ]; then c='HEAD'; else c=$1; fi; git difftool --tool=meld -y $c~..$c; }; f"
```

This will launch meld to show the diffs introduced by that commit:

```
git showm <branch or hash>
```

Without an argument, it will use `HEAD` as a default:

```
git showm
```

As a bonus, you can follow that up with a bash alias to get tab completion for branch names by adding this to the `~/.bashrc`

```
alias showm='git showm'
__git_complete showm _git_show
```

Comment: For merge commits, `git diff HEAD~..HEAD` is not equivalent to `git show`. I'm using the latter specifically to review forward integrations (verifying that merge conflicts were properly resolved). `git diff` is not an alternative there. Not even close.

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple, you just have the wrong command-key in your git config.

It should be like this:

```
[diff "csv_diff"]
    textconv = Tools/csv_diff
```

This works in `git show` and all other places where a diff is displayed (even in `gitk`).

I tried this with `git version 2.24.1.windows.2` and this configfiles:

**gitconfig**

```
[diff "zip"]
    textconv = unzip -c -a
[diff "tgz"]
    binary = true
    textconv = tar -xvzO -f
[diff "gz"]
    binary = true
    textconv = gunzip -c
```

**gitattributes**

```
*.zip diff=zip
*.tgz diff=tgz
*.tar.gz diff=tgz
*.sql.gz diff=gz
```

If your command don`t likes to have the filename as last parameter you can do somethime like this:

```
[diff "sqlite3"]
    binary = true
    textconv = "f() { sqlite3 $1 --readonly .dump; }; f"
```

Where the `$1` stands for the place where the filename is inserted.
Maybe you must enclose `$1` into single quotes to support filenames with spaces.