# Alternative diff algorithm for special file extension for Git

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I want to use an alternative diff algorithm for special file extension, e.g. ".java" and the standart diff algorithm for other files.

I can make it via *.gitattributes* file:

```
*.java diff=javadiffprogramm
```

and *.gitconfig* file:

```
[diff "javadiffprogramm"]
    command = pathToDiffProgram.
```

**My question is what is the format of input parameters of "javadiffprogramm" and where it should output the result of diff?** The result of diff has the format like "@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@...".

Some questions on this topic:

- [Using custom diff tool with `git show`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885397/using-custom-diff-tool-with-git-show)
- [Is it possible to set diff/merge-tool for a specific file extension in git-extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663296/is-it-possible-to-set-diff-merge-tool-for-a-specific-file-extension-in-git-exten)
- [Setup 'git diff' for special file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069976/setup-git-diff-for-special-file-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in [the git man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) as `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`.

> GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF
>
> When the environment variable GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF is set, the program named by it is called, instead of the diff invocation described above. For a path that is added, removed, or modified, GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF is called with 7 parameters:
>
> ```
> path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode
> ```

The docs go on to explain what those parameters are.

Output should be to STDOUT.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have found about 7 input parameters, but nothing about Output. Maybe I wasn't attentive.

Comment: @NAlmaz I couldn't find information about output either. It's an educated guess based on how Unix tools generally work. If Git wants the output written elsewhere it can redirect it itself.